# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-amount"

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, spyder

Quisiera que los datos que tengo en SQLite se vieran listados en una tabla que trato de hacer en tk inter. Esto funciona para mis dos primeras columnas "Nombre de la Muestra" y "Responsable" pero para la columna de "Cantidad": `self.tree.insert('', 0,  values = row[1], text = row[2], amount = [3])`
^
este amount aparece como unknown option, qué puedo hacer? Me encuentro aprendiendo a usar python y tk inter, gracias!

El error que sale es

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "InventarioSkeleton.py", line 111, in <module>
    application = Muestra(window)  #Ventana creada sin ejecutarse
  File "InventarioSkeleton.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.get_product()
  File "InventarioSkeleton.py", line 85, in get_product
    self.tree.insert('', 0,  values = row[1], text = row[2], amount = [3])
  File "/home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/ttk.py", line 1369, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-amount"
```

El código es

```
from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import * 

import sqlite3  

class Muestra: 

    db_name = 'Database - Muestras'

    def __init__(self, window): #constructor de la clase

        self.wind = window  #

        self.wind.title('Invetario Muestras')
        
        
    #Frame como contenedor(para agregar elementos dentro de este)
        
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registrar nueva muestra')

        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)  

    #Entrada nombre de la muestra:
        
        Label(frame, text = 'Nombre de la muestra: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.sample = Entry(frame)  

        self.sample.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
    #Entrada nombre del responsable:

        Label(frame, text = 'Responsable: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        
    #Entrada de Cantidad de muestra:
        
        Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.amount = Entry(frame)
        self.amount.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    
        
    #Botón de agregar muestra
        
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar muestra').grid(row = 4, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E) #Con sticky hago que el botón ocupe todo el ancho disponible 
        
        
    #Tabla para listar las muestras
        
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3')) 

        self.tree.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Nombre de la muestra', anchor = CENTER) 

        self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Responsable', anchor = CENTER) 

        self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Cantidad', anchor = CENTER)
        
        self.get_product()
    
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):  

        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()   

            resultado =  cursor.execute(query, parameters)  

            conn.commit()  
        return resultado  

    def get_product(self): 

    
    #Limpieza de la tabla 
    
        records = self.tree.get_children() 

        for element in records:    

        
    #Consultando los datos
        
        query = 'SELECT * FROM InventarioMuestras ORDER BY id DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)  

    #Llenando los datos
        
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('', 0,  values = row[1], text = row[2], amount = [3])

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    window =  Tk()  
    application = Muestra(window)  
    window.mainloop()  #La ventana se ejecuta
```

Comment: El método insert del treeview no acepta ningún argumento llamado amount: [ver documentacion](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html#:~:text=.insert(parent%2C%20index%2C%20iid%3DNone%2C%20**kw)). Cual sería la intención al pasar ese argumento?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo que sucede es que en mi base de datos tengo 3 columnas: 'Nombre de muestra', Responsable' y 'Cantidad' ;deseo que los datos presentes en la base de datos sean visualizados en la tabla que anteriormente cree. Esto lo estaba haciendo con el método insert pero al usar los argumentos que si son permitidos [enlace](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html#:~:text=.insert(parent%2C%20index%2C%20iid%3DNone%2C%20%2A%2Akw)) , el dato de 'Cantidad no aparece en la tabla.

Comment: El argumento values acepta una tupla de valores, el primer valor se pone en la columna "#1", el segundo en "#2" y así sucesivamente. text indica el valor en la primera columna. En tu caso particular tendrías que hacer `self.tree.insert('', 'end',  values = row[1:], text = row[0])`. Cambié el 0 por un 'end' para que cada nueva fila se ponga al final del treeview y no al principio (tal como estaba, se agregarían los registros en el orden inverso al esperado).